# adding row to an existing table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

guys i jnow it is dummy question but i spent hours in this and cant reach .. i want to add row to an existing table and this row consists of checkbox and 4 textboxes .. when i run it the textboxes appears but the checkbox dont .. here is my code

```
function addRow() {
var i = 1;
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);    
var html = [];
html.push("<table id='table'>\n<body>");
html.push("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td>");
var cell = row.insertCell(html);

for ( var propertyNames in grid.data[0]) {
    cell = row.insertCell(i);

    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.type = "text";
    element.size = 10;
    element.name = "input"+i;
    cell.appendChild(element);
    html.push("<td>" + cell + "</td>");
    i++;
}
html.push("</tr>");
html.push("</body>\n</table>");
}
```

Comment: You are having a mix of dom elements and html content? why not just create the html string for the input also

Comment: who is using the `html` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a array with the markup for the checkbox, but it is never added to the table

```js
function addRow() {
  var i = 1;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var cell = row.insertCell();
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "checkbox";
  element.name = "chk";
  cell.appendChild(element);

  for (var propertyNames in grid.data[0]) {
    cell = row.insertCell(i);

    element = document.createElement("input");
    element.type = "text";
    element.size = 10;
    element.name = "input" + i;
    cell.appendChild(element);
    i++;
  }
}

var grid = {
  data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 1
  }]
};
addRow();
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```